# ImageMagick to Wand: problem with sparse-color Barycentric

Tags: python, wand

I don't know how to convert an ImageMagick to Wand instruction.

```
convert beijing_contrast.jpg \
          -sparse-color Barycentric '0,0 black 0,%h white' \
          -function polynomial 4,-4,1   beijing_blurmap.jpg
```

`img.function('polynomial', [4, -4, 1])` seems OK, but for `-sparse-color` instruction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Wand, the method `Image.spase_color()` can be called by passing a `dict` map.

Although you would not be able to use percent escape (`%h`) arguments.

```py
with Image(filename='beijing_contrast.jpg') as img:
    points = {'black': (0, 0), 'white': (0, img.height)}
    img.sparse_color('barycentric', points)
    img.function('polynomial', [4, -4, 1])
    img.save(filename='beijing_blurmap.jpg')
```